# Filtering with combo in Access not working properly

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I've been trying to filter the result of a SQL query by using a combo box. I need it to be done with AfterUpdate() because I need it to show all the resutls (unfiltered) and then, if wanted, filter based on the content of the combo box.

Here "Cuadro_combinado30" is the name of the combo box and "Dossier" is the name of the field I want to filter by.

```
Private Sub Cuadro_combinado30_AfterUpdate()

Dim strFilter As String

With Me.Cuadro_combinado30
    If IsNull(.Value) Or .Value = "**ALL**" Then
       ' If the combo box is cleared or ALL selected, clear the form filter.
       Me.Filter = vbNullString
       Me.FilterOn = False
    Else
        ' item other than ALL is selected, filter for an exact match.
        strFilter = "[Dossier] = '" & _
            Replace(.Value, "'", "''") & "'"
        Debug.Print strFilter ' check this in Immediate window in case of 
        ' trouble you can use Ctrl+g to go to the Immediate window
        Me.Filter = strFilter
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If
    End With

End Sub
```

So far, the result has been that when I enter the form, all results are showing, but when I select one option of the combo box in order to filter the results, then the query does not seem to find anything as no result is shown.

Why is this code not working and what should I modify for it to work?

Thank you.

UPDATE: I've tried to use a text box instead of a combo box, and it works, when I type something on the text box the results are filtered based on what I just wrote. I guess it has to do with how the combo box is created, it seems that even when the combo box is showing content, the filter finds a NULL on it.

Comment: Does the combo have several columns?

Comment: No, when creating on the wizard it only shows one column of data, which is how it should be, I think it could have to do with the last stage of the wizard, when it asks what to do with the value, either remembering the value or storing it somewhere else.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz After cheking it on properties, yes, it has two columns. Why is that if I only selected one column when creating the combo box?

Comment: Ok so there is the problem. Change the combo properties to one column.

Comment: Try `Replace(.Column(1), "'", "''")`

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you, replacing column 1 worked perfectly. The problem is solved but I'd like to know anywa, before trying @Santosh solotuion, I've tried to set the numbers of columns on 1 on properties, but then the combo became empty on the form, why is that?

Comment: @ALawliet You are welcome :)

Comment: One last question, how can I add an option to the combo in order to select all the options? I mean, once I select a filter, I cannot go back to show all the unfiltered resutls.

Comment: When you make the combo box `combinado30` null, it should show you all the records.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the combo box has 2 columns instead of one, @Santosh solution worked perfectly:

```
 Replace(.Column(1), "'", "''")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the combo properties to one column should solve the problem